# How to verify google analytics when you don't have a site attached to an application on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, google-analytics

How can I verify my google analytics tracking code without having an actual website?
I'm just going to use it for my app tracking (pageviews/events).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a website but instead what to track activity inside a mobile application you will need to use the Google Analytics Mobile SDK (http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/).

I would try creating test code that hits the API with your tracking ID and see if it shows up in the Google Analytics dashboard.

Comment: This was not the solution, as I was already using the SDK. It wasn't tracking anything so I decided to verify the track code using an empty webpage. But still thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you init the library with your app's analytics id:

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"your-apps-google-analytics-id"
                                       dispatchPeriod:15
                                             delegate:nil];

#if DEBUG
    NSLog(@"******* WARNING: ANALYTICS IN DRY RUN MODE! *******");
    [[GANTracker sharedTracker] setDryRun:YES]; // DO NOT COLLECT ANALLYTICS
#endif
```

Track screen views as if they were page hits:

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"/Tutorial" withError:nil];
```

Track event/actions:

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"Registration"
                                action:@"Skipped"
                                 label:nil
                                 value:0
                             withError:nil];
```